# Rotating an embedded pdf in html5

Tags: javascript, html, css, pdf

I am displaying a pdf in a webpage using html5 and css3:

```
<embed class="pdf" src="/files/test.pdf" type="application/pdf">
```

The actual file varies depending on selections and user uploads on the webpage, but given the context I know that in the majority of cases, the user is going to have to rotate the pdf to makes sense of it.  This is generally easy to do manually by right-clicking and selecting "rotate".  However, since I know it is necessary, I want to present them rotated.  The only way I have found so far is to use a css `transform`, but this also rotates the menu and scrollbar, which I don't want.

Is there any way, using css or javascript, to tell the browser to apply rotation to the embedded pdf?  I mainly need this to work on Chrome, so a browser-specific solution is fine.

Comment: Hi @aquavitae, Can you please give some idea on solution for this problem, I'm too engaged in this problem.

Comment: You could try something like:`PDFViewerApplication.pdfViewer.pagesRotation = 90`

Answer (score -1):

In Chrome you can use Ctrl+] to rotate clockwise and Ctrl+[ to rotate counter clockwise

**EDITED**

If you need to do this using script then probably you could use PDF.js following instructions on this link: https://blog.oio.de/2014/04/11/integrating-pdf-js-pdf-viewer-web-application/ and host your viewer locally to avoid cross domain issues

Then you can easily embed viewer into iframe on your page and access the contents of the iframe to rotate the PDF.

Code as is below:

```
var rotatedeg = 90;
var rotate_css = 
{
'-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + rotatedeg + 'deg)',
'-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + rotatedeg + 'deg)',
'-ms-transform': 'rotate(' + rotatedeg + 'deg)',
'-o-transform': 'rotate(' + rotatedeg + 'deg)',
'transform': 'rotate(' + rotatedeg + 'deg)'
};
// my-frame is id of iframe
 $("#my-frame").contents().find("#viewer").css(rotate_css);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It doesn't work here with these keystrokes, though it works via the popup menu. But it was asked to rotate via css or javascript not via keyboard/menu.

Comment: this doesn't work, could you please explain this a bit.